# Prove or disprove: $\lVert T\rVert=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert=1}|\langle Tx,x\rangle|$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T$ is bdd linear operator.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Edit: To clarify, note that $T:H\to H$.

This is a problem on an old preliminary exam in Analysis that I'm working through to prep for my own prelim.

My initial thought was to disprove it, but I can't seem to do that. I've been using $\ell^2$ as my $H$ and thinking up various potential counterexamples, but every time either the equality in the title ends up being true, or else my $T$ winds up not being bdd linear.

Am I on the right track to be trying to disprove rather than prove? And either way, any tips for strategies would be appreciated.

Comment: This statement is false. There are 2-dimensional counterexamples. Can you make $\langle Tx,x \rangle = 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: @HansEngler How's this: $T(x_1,x_2)=(-x_2,x_1)$. Then $\langle Tx,x\rangle=0\ \forall x\in\mathbb R^2$. Yet (under the 2-norm) $\lVert T \rVert = 1$.

Comment: @HansEngler That can't be done in the complex case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\ip[2]{\langle#1,#2\rangle}$
It's false. For example define $T:\Bbb C^2\to\Bbb C^2$ by $$T(x_1,x_2)=(x_2,0);$$then $||T||=1$ while the AM-GM inequality followed by Holder's inequality shows that $$|\ip {Tx}x|\le\frac{||x||^2}{2}.$$

It should probably be noted that it's less trivially false in the complex case than in the real case. As has been pointed out, if you define $T:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ by $T(x_1,x_2)=(x_2,x_1)$ then $\ip{Tx}x=0$ for every $x$, while on the other hand

**Lemma** If $H$ is a complex inner-product space, $T:H\to H$ is linear, and $\ip{Tx}x=0$ for all $x\in H$ then $T=0$.

Proof: Considering $0=\ip{T(x+y)}{x+y}=\ip{T(x+iy)}{x+iy}$ shows that $\ip{Tx}y=0$ for all $x,y\in H$.